# CMake Produces Makefile that Linker Doesn't Like

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to modernize a build system with CMake. When I try to compile the program with `make` I get this output

```sh
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../armgcc.cmake" .. && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ~/cmake_test/build
Scanning dependencies of target testproj
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/testproj.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable testproj
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/nosys.specs: attempt to rename spec 'link_gcc_c_sequence' to already defined spec 'nosys_link_gcc_c_sequence'
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testproj.dir/build.make:84: testproj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/testproj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

With `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(testproj VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(testproj main.c)
```

and `armgcc.cmake`

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --specs=nosys.specs")
```

What are `link_gcc_sequence` and `nosys_link_gcc_sequence`, and how should I structure my CMakeLists to avoid renaming them?

Comment: You may check parameters, which are actually passed to the linker, with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Thanks, using that I saw `link.txt` wound up calling `--specs=nosys.specs` twice. For some reason removing `${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}` from the armgcc call fixed it.

Comment: Please write an answer yourself, and mark it. This way others seeking help will recognize the solved question.